# how do you pull random values from one method into another?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

long story short. im supposed to write a program with a single-dimension array that holds 10 integer numbers and sort the array using a bubble sort.

now so far I have written:

```
System.out.print("The unsorted list is: ");
         int[] numbers = new int[10];       
            //Generates 10 Random Numbers in the range 1 -100
            for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
              numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
              System.out.print(numbers[i] + " " );
           }//end for loop
```

but i dont clearly understand how to pass random values from one method to another. the proffesor was kind enough to include a bubble sort code, but im not enterely clear on how its supposed to pull random values from the array in the main method.

the bubblesort code:

```
 public static void bubbleSort(int[] list) 
      {
        int temp;

          for (int i = list.length - 1; i > 0; i--) 
          {
             for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
             {
               if (list[j] > list[j + 1]) 
               {
               temp = list[j];
               list[j] = list[j + 1];
               list[j + 1] = temp;
               }
             }
          }
       }
```

any tips or help is greatly apreciated.

Comment: `bubbleSort(numbers);`

Comment: Can you please be specific. Mention the method from where you want to pull random values and the method where you want to put them. I suggest you do a research on how bubble sort works if you are confused with its functioning. Here is a resource http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
public static void bubbleSort(int[] list)
```

is expecting `int[] list` an integer array as parameter, So you pass an integer array.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   int[] mList = {12,3,54,67,8,90};
   bubbleSort(mList);
   for(int i = 0 ; i < mList.length ; i++)
      System.out.println(mList[i] + ", ");
}
```

Just so you know, notice that `void main(String[] args)` also expects an array (String array) as arguments.

Also since the argument `int[] list` is a non primitive (ie. not a plain int, float, char, or their wrapper Object), the arguments are received as reference not values. And so whatever modification is done in the array will be reflected in the main function also.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
System.out.print("The unsorted list is: ");
         int[] numbers = new int[10];  
               bubbleSort(numbers);
            //Generates 10 Random Numbers in the range 1 -100
            for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
              numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
              System.out.print(numbers[i] + " " );
           }//end for loop

 public static void bubbleSort(int[] list) 
      {
        int temp;

          for (int i = list.length - 1; i > 0; i--) 
          {
             for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
             {
               if (list[j] > list[j + 1]) 
               {
               temp = list[j];
               list[j] = list[j + 1];
               list[j + 1] = temp;
               }
             }
          }
       }
```